# JavaScript Snake Game with two Snakes (Local Mutiplayer)

Tags: javascript, html, 2d-games

Im programing a Snake Webgame with HTML, CSS and JavaScript and im implementing Multiple Gamemodes, one should be a Local Multiplayer where one Person is playing with Arrow keys and the Other Person with WASD.

But I got the problem, that I dont know how to Summon a Second Snake. I tried to just copy the Summon Code and rename the variables. But that didn't work, no matter what I tryed.

The code is 90% made by myself, but because of some JavaScript beginner issues I needed some help by the web.

**Can someone may tell me how I can summon a Second snake? I just need the "how to" Summon.**

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('game');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let grid = 10;
let count = 0;

//Scores
let Score = 0;
let HighScore = 0;

let Alive = true;

//Snake Speed
let Speed = 15;

//Snake Base Stats
let snake = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  dx: grid,
  dy: 0,
  cells: [],
  maxCells: 4
};

//First Apple Spawn
let apple = {
  x: 320,
  y: 320
};

//Random Int for Apple Spawn
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

  //Tic speed
  if (++count < Speed) {
    return;
  }

  count = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  snake.x += snake.dx;
  snake.y += snake.dy;

  //Automatic Movement
  if (snake.x < 0) {
    snake.x = canvas.width - grid;
  } else if (snake.x >= canvas.width) {
    snake.x = 0;
  }

  if (snake.y < 0) {
    snake.y = canvas.height - grid;
  } else if (snake.y >= canvas.height) {
    snake.y = 0;
  }


  snake.cells.unshift({
    x: snake.x,
    y: snake.y
  });

  if (snake.cells.length > snake.maxCells) {
    snake.cells.pop();
  }

  //Apple Color
  ctx.fillStyle = 'gold';
  ctx.fillRect(apple.x, apple.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);

  //Snake Color
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  snake.cells.forEach(function(cell, index) {
    //Snake Color
    ctx.fillRect(cell.x, cell.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);

    //Snake Eat Apple
    if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) {
      snake.maxCells++;
      apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
      apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
      SnakeScore();
    }

    //Snake Dies
    for (var i = index + 1; i < snake.cells.length; i++) {

      if (cell.x === snake.cells[i].x && cell.y === snake.cells[i].y) {

        SummonSnake();
        Alive = false;
        SnakeScore();
      }
    }
  });
}


//Arrow Key Movement
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  if (e.which === 37 && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = -grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
  } else if (e.which === 38 && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = -grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
  } else if (e.which === 39 && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
  } else if (e.which === 40 && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
  }
});

requestAnimationFrame(loop);

//Score
function SnakeScore() {

  if (Alive === true) {
    Score++;
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
  } else if (Alive === false) {
    Score = 0;
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
    Alive = true;
  }
  if (Score > HighScore) {
    SnakeHighscore();
  }
}

//Highscore
function SnakeHighscore() {

  HighScore = Score;
  document.getElementById("Highscore").innerHTML = HighScore;

}

//Snake Summon Stats
function SummonSnake() {

  snake.x = 200;
  snake.y = 200;
  snake.cells = [];
  snake.maxCells = 4;
  snake.dx = grid;
  snake.dy = 0;

}

//Gamemodes
function GameMode() {
  value = document.getElementById('valueGames').value;

  if (value === "E") {
    Speed = 15;
    Score = 0;
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
    SummonSnake();
  } else if (value === "M") {
    Speed = 10;
    Score = 0;
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
    SummonSnake();
  } else if (value === "H") {
    Speed = 5;
    Score = 0;
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
    SummonSnake();
  } else if (value === "Multiplayer") {

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3493594.png');
}

canvas {
  width: 403px;
  height: 403px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 213, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#ScoreCSS {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Snake NICEEE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Scores -->
  <h1 id="ScoreCSS">Score: <a id="Score">0</a></h1>
  <h1>Highscore: <a id="Highscore">0</a></h1>

  <!-- Canvas (Game Field)-->
  <canvas id="game" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

  <!-- Dropdown for GameModes -->
  <select id="valueGames" onchange="GameMode()">
    <option value="E" selected>Easy</option>
    <option value="M">Middle</option>
    <option value="H">Hard</option>
    <option value="Multiplayer">Multiplayer</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you update your code to show the duplicated variables? You need to at least add new variables for `Alive`, `Speed`, and `snake`. And then update your `loop()` to account for the second variables (i.e. `snake2.x += snake2.dx;`). Then in `SummonSnake()` you'll also need to update `snake2` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. I created a second `snake` object and moved the alive property to the `snake`. Then I added functions to draw/move the snake and passed the `snake` object to those functions so you don't have as much duplicate code in order to handle multiple snakes. (Theoretically, you could add more than 2 snakes this way by creating new snake objects and then adding `moveSnake(snake3, canvas);` etc).

You'll need to add the event listeners for WASD as well as "dead" game logic in Multiplayer mode, because presumably the game will pause somehow and show the winner and the high score.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('game');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let grid = 10;
let count = 0;

//Scores
let Score = 0;
let HighScore = 0;

let Speed = 15;

//Snake Base Stats
let snake = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  dx: grid,
  dy: 0,
  cells: [],
  maxCells: 4,
  alive: true, // moved the global var here
  active: true, // added this in order to track multiple snakes being active
  color: 'white' // moved this here to define it per-snake
};

let snake2 = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  dx: grid,
  dy: 0,
  cells: [],
  maxCells: 4,
  alive: true,
  active: false,
  color: 'red'
};

// keep track of active snakes
let snakes = [
  snake
];

//First Apple Spawn
let apple = {
  x: 320,
  y: 320,
  color: 'gold'
};

//Random Int for Apple Spawn
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

  //Tic speed
  if (++count < Speed) {
    return;
  }

  count = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  moveSnakes(snakes, canvas);

  //Apple Color
  ctx.fillStyle = apple.color;
  ctx.fillRect(apple.x, apple.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);

  drawSnakes(snakes, ctx, apple);
}


//Arrow Key Movement
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  if (e.which === 37 && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = -grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
  } else if (e.which === 38 && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = -grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
  } else if (e.which === 39 && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
  } else if (e.which === 40 && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
  }
});

//TODO: add movement for snake2

requestAnimationFrame(loop);

function moveSnakes(snakes, canvas) {
  snakes.forEach(function(snake) {
    if (!snake.active) {
      return;
    }

    snake.x += snake.dx;
    snake.y += snake.dy;

    if (snake.x < 0) {
      snake.x = canvas.width - grid;
    } else if (snake.x >= canvas.width) {
      snake.x = 0;
    }

    if (snake.y < 0) {
      snake.y = canvas.height - grid;
    } else if (snake.y >= canvas.height) {
      snake.y = 0;
    }

    snake.cells.unshift({
      x: snake.x,
      y: snake.y
    });

    if (snake.cells.length > snake.maxCells) {
      snake.cells.pop();
    }
  });
}

function drawSnakes(snakes, ctx, apple) {
  snakes.forEach(function(snake) {
    if (!snake.active) {
      return;
    }

    //Snake Color
    ctx.fillStyle = snake.color;

    snake.cells.forEach(function(cell, index) {
      //Snake Color
      ctx.fillRect(cell.x, cell.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);

      //Snake Eat Apple
      if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) {
        snake.maxCells++;
        apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        SnakeScore(snake);
      }

      //Snake Dies
      for (var i = index + 1; i < snake.cells.length; i++) {

        if (cell.x === snake.cells[i].x && cell.y === snake.cells[i].y) {

          SummonSnake(snake);
          snake.alive = false;
          SnakeScore();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

//Score
function SnakeScore(snake) {

  if (snake.alive) {
    Score++;
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
  } else if (!snake.alive) {
    Score = 0;
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
    snake.alive = true;
  }
  if (Score > HighScore) {
    SnakeHighscore();
  }
}

//Highscore
function SnakeHighscore() {

  HighScore = Score;
  document.getElementById("Highscore").innerHTML = HighScore;

}

//Snake Summon Stats
function SummonSnake(snake, y) {

  snake.x = 200;
  snake.y = y;
  snake.cells = [];
  snake.maxCells = 4;
  snake.dx = grid;
  snake.dy = 0;

}

function activateSnakes(numberOfSnakes) {
  if (numberOfSnakes === 1) {
    SummonSnake(snake, 200);
    snakes = [snake];
    snake2.active = false;
  } else if (numberOfSnakes === 2) {
    SummonSnake(snake, 180);
    SummonSnake(snake2, 220);
    snakes = [snake, snake2];
    snake2.active = true;
  }
}

//Gamemodes
function GameMode() {
  value = document.getElementById('valueGames').value;

  if (value === "E") {
    Speed = 15;
    activateSnakes(1);
  } else if (value === "M") {
    Speed = 10;
    activateSnakes(1);
  } else if (value === "H") {
    Speed = 5;
    activateSnakes(1);
  } else if (value === "Multiplayer") {
    Speed = 5;
    activateSnakes(2);
  }
  
  Score = 0;
  document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = Score;
}

GameMode();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3493594.png');
}

canvas {
  width: 403px;
  height: 403px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 213, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#ScoreCSS {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Snake NICEEE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Scores -->
  <h1 id="ScoreCSS">Score: <a id="Score">0</a></h1>
  <h1>Highscore: <a id="Highscore">0</a></h1>

  <!-- Canvas (Game Field)-->
  <canvas id="game" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

  <!-- Dropdown for GameModes -->
  <select id="valueGames" onchange="GameMode()">
    <option value="E">Easy</option>
    <option value="M">Middle</option>
    <option value="H">Hard</option>
    <option value="Multiplayer" selected>Multiplayer</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works like that, and sry for not answering your Comment... I just saw it in the moment you answered the question.

Comment: I updated my answer by abstracting things a little bit more and setting the gamemode to `Multiplayer` on load (and calling `GameMode()` on page load) for faster testing :)